# C#, Vici Parser Conditional Statements

Tags: c#, vici

Can any one help me out to evaluate this expression at runtime using Vici parser.

I have tried other usual expressions like 5* VARIABLE kinda expression. But is it possible to evaluate conditional statements using VICI parser.

Example:
IF SAL > 5 THEN 25 ELSE 45 ENDIF

Thanks...

Comment: This structure is not possible.

Probably we can use ternary operator {?:)

so the  expression can be given as : **(sal > 5 ? 25: 45)**


But I am not sure, what do we do if we need a tree-structured coondition like

if( sal > 7) then 3
else if( 10 > sal > 7) then 5
else 6

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ?: syntax:

```
SAL > 5 ? 25 : 45
```

You can expand this for multiple conditions as well:

```
SAL > 5 ? 25 : SAL > 10 ? 35 : 45
```

Comment: Thanks, Philippe. I got to know this but wanted this to be more readable. Since this needs to be entered by user. So, I don't want an user to know abt what language are we using. So asked. But thanks for your  reply